# kivy syntax error - conditions inside widget_add

Tags: python, kivy

I have got a syntax error in my kivy application. Is it because i can't have conditions inside widget_add? How can i make it work like this?

```
    def status(what):
        object = what
        self.add_widget(
            Label(
                text='You selected '+object+', please wait...',
                size_hint=(.3, .1)
                if object == "car":
                    pos_hint={'center_x': .3, 'center_y': .6}
                elif object == "tree":
                    color = (1,0,0,1),
                    pos_hint={'center_x': .7, 'center_y': .6}
            )
        )
```

**error:**

```
running "python.exe C:\Users\Somebody\Desktop\Kivy\test.py" \n
  File "C:\Users\Slugma\Somebody\Kivy\test.py", line 51
    if object == "vnc":
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, you cannot have conditionals inside a function's arguments. Move your `if...elif` conditional outside (just after the `object = what` line), calculate the value of `pos_hint`, then call `self.add_widget(Label(args))`.